Playwright - route.fetch: Test ended error
In my SPA, I am using page.route() to intercept an api request. Ex: /core
The same api is getting called multiple times when I move across the pages and finally, test fails with a message route.fetch: Test ended error.
From the traces, I could understand that when the api is called first time, it is getting fulfilled, but the second time, before it gets fulfilled, test completes.
await page.route(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/enterprise/*/core`,
    async (route) => {
      const response = await route.fetch();
      const json = await response.json();
      json.devices = devicesJson;
      await route.fulfill({ response, json });
    });

I had given an explicit wait for couple of seconds at the end of the test solves the problem, but is there any better solution?

Please share a [mcve].
